# Make error in caffe (I guess relate on Openmp,gcc)

Tags: caffe

I build to https://github.com/liulei01/DRBox

`make -j8` 's Output

[image]

OS : ubuntu 14.04

cuda : 7.5

cudnn : 5.1v

gcc : 4.6.4

what can i do?